# Add an 'active' class to list items

Tags: jquery

I have created a form which is split into four parts using a jQuery script I found here at SO. When the user has finished filling in one part of the form, s/he clicks 'next' and moves on to the next part of the form or clicks 'back' to go back to the previous part.

I'd like to add an ordered list above the form which has the title of the four form parts and adds an 'active' class on li 1 when the user is viewing form part 1, an 'active' class on li 2 when user is viewing form part 2 and so on.

I'm not much of a jQuery expert so not sure how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here's the ordered list:

```
<ol>
  <li class="active">Part 1</li> /* 'active' when user is viewing part 1 */
  <li>Part 2</li>
  <li>Part 3</li>
  <li>Part 4</li>
</ol>
```

Here's the jQuery script:

```
    var tab_pool = ["form-part-1", "form-part-2", "form-part-3", "form-part-4"];
    var visible = $(".tab:visible").attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    var curr_ind = $.inArray(visible, tab_pool);
    $(".submit").hide();
    $(".back").hide();

    var validator = $('form').validate({
    ignore: 'input[type="button"],input[type="submit"]',
    });

    $('.next').click(function () {
        var tab = $(".tab:visible");

        var valid = true;
        $('input', tab).each(function(i, v){
            valid = validator.element(v) && valid;
        });

        if(!valid){
            return;
        }

        if (curr_ind < 3) {
            $(".tab:visible").css({position:"absolute",left:"-9999px"}).animate({left: -9999});
            curr_ind = curr_ind + 1;
            $("." + tab_pool[curr_ind]).css({position:"static",left:"auto"}).animate({left: 0});
            $(".submit").hide();
            $(".back").show();
        }
        if (curr_ind == 3) {
            $(".submit").show();
            $(".next").hide();
        }
    });

    $('.back').click(function () {
        if (curr_ind > 0) {
            $(".tab:visible").css({position:"absolute",left:"-9999px"}).animate({left: -9999});
            curr_ind = curr_ind - 1;
            $("." + tab_pool[curr_ind]).css({position:"static",left:"auto"}).animate({left: 0});
            $(".submit").hide();
            $(".next").show();
        }
        if (curr_ind == 0) {
            $(".back").hide();
        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your next and back click functions, add the following at the end of each:

```
$('li').removeClass('active').eq(curr_ind).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Sure thing, if you need an explanation let me know.